# NextJS - Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression- /node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

While running NextJS project, it takes too much time to load page and page is not displaying too

> `warn  - ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js Critical
> dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js

`

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: its newly created project with NextJS 13.1.2